# Connect Git History of multiple Repos

Tags: git

I try out to make a Git History Cut and connect the historys of the 2 repos.

**Git Log repo "archiv":**

```
9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a 3
1d0e5abe5daf60c0d86819938ba1aefd44b87ff5 2
766f4880e8ccf61bdc718dfae62466f800ae8119 1
```

**Git Log repo "new":**

```
2932c4b8ea681f0a97bf151ccc46d2044e8e5a50 5
27ec1a4618f1bf0025b8ba83fd69c2607cdf78d4 4
```

I linked the both repos in the alternates file and connect it with

```
git replace --graft 27ec1a4618f1bf0025b8ba83fd69c2607cdf78d4 9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a
```

and it worked, so i see on my repo **new** the old commits of the **archiv**.

---

**Problem:**

But now i want to split the repo **new** and make a second history cut. So i get the repo **new2** with new commits.

**Git Log repo "new2":**

```
90c767f43f35a2e21d8a3b8b3741495bd8afeff3 7
6c396ae0bff3ffba267a7a280c36174413ffc20c 6
```

But now if I write the repo **new**-path in the alternates file of **new2** and linked this with `git replace` I see only the commits of **new** and **new2**, and not the linked **archiv** to **new**.

I try to add the **archiv**-path to the alternates file of **new2**

```
C:\GIT\RepoCut\3fach\archiv.git\objects
C:\GIT\RepoCut\3fach\new.git\objects
```

and make a `git replace` on commit **4** and **3** to see all commits, but I get the error and my old connection with **new** breaks:

```
does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates./objects
fatal: could not parse 27ec1a4618f1bf0025b8ba83fd69c2607cdf78d4
```

Can I linked a second repo (**archiv**) to my repo **new2** to see the full history?

Answer (score 0):

**The content of the .git/objects/info/alternates file has to follow definition of environment variable**

The paths have to be, therefore, separated by a semicolon (;) and content of your file should look like:

```
C:\GIT\RepoCut\3fach\archiv.git\objects;C:\GIT\RepoCut\3fach\new.git\objects
```